# Listing all sub-resources without parent scope

Tags: rest, api-design

Let's say I have `User` resource which has `Address` sub-resource (let's forget about why this is a resource instead of attribute). To get a user's address, I can do
`GET /users/{id}/address`

Now I want to have an API which returns all the addresses regardless of their owners. I can do
`GET /addresses`. This feels a little bit hacky.

Another option is to move the `Address` resource to the top level.

- `GET /user-addresses` to get all addresses
- `GET /user-addresses/{user-id}` to get a specific user's address
- `POST /user-addresses/{user-id}` to create an address

Which one do you prefer? Have you seen similar patterns before? Thanks!

Comment: A lot of common tools use a reserved token, like _all_. So, you would get **/users/all/address/**. This morning, I've used **rfkill unblock all**.

Comment: Which one we prefer is irrelevant to you. That said, what's wrong with `/addresses`? It's fine if you really want to provide consumers with addresses regardless of the users. The rest of the URIS suggested here keeps involving users some way or another.

Comment: @Laiv, I was struggling a bit at the time because I felt that the `resources` are in two different layers. But anyway I ended up with this approach and forgot about the resource thing as defined in RESTful. At the end of the day, solving the business problem is the ultimate goal.

Comment: That's a good point. Here another one. The only one reading the URI is the http client. A program.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return all of the user's addresses, then I would map that to `/users/addresses`.

Moving address outside of the users resource in the endpoint tells me I'm getting more than just user addresses (ie. Store address). I'm assuming that's not what you're going for.

And anything like user-adresses sitting beside the user endpoint looks very messy, I'd avoid that.

Comment: The `/users/addresses` looks like a user resource and the id is `addresses`. So the path more or less conflicts with the `/users/{id}`.

Comment: I disagree, but if you're actually worried about that then go with `/addresses` or `/users/*/address`

Answer (score 1):

REST is a limited concept. It's a good mechanism to read and write individual data objects or small sets. There is no answer in REST itself on querying, paging, sorting, command execution or god beware asymmetry or CQRS. That doesn't mean it's not good, but the answers vary. Most APIs in fact have a need for querying, paging and sorting to handle larger amounts of data. One can look to [json:api](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sorting) for one example for such semantics.

I would look at the paths where the client will locate addresses from a use case perspective. Need to find all users in a zip code? fine,

```
/addresses?zip=12345
```

On the other hand,

```
/users/*/addresses?zip=12345
```

doesn't sound right for me. We are not reading users with adresses in ZIP code 12345. We are reading addresses in ZIP code 12345.